# Deploying platform-specific Maven snapshots from separate build jobs

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, artifactory, snapshot

I have a Maven project which outputs platform-specific artifacts for three platforms: Linux, Windows and MacOS. I have implemented this by putting the OS/arch combination into the classifier, i.e. win-amd64, mac-x86_64, linux-amd64.

The artifacts must be built on the platform they relate to, i.e. the Windows artifact can only be generated on a Windows machine and so on. So I have separate Jenkins jobs running the Maven build, one per platform. This all works fine for deployment and for downloading releases but unfortunately other build that want to consume snapshots of these artifacts cannot use a version like `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` to access them. They have to use the full timestamp and build number.

The problem is that because the builds have different build numbers and timestamps, the maven-metadata.xml gets rewritten on each deployment, and only the latest SNAPSHOT is referenced. It's basically a race where the slowest build wins. The top of the maven-metadata.xml in the repository looks like this:

```xml
<version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<versioning>
  <snapshot>
    <timestamp>20210303.091119</timestamp>
    <buildNumber>18</buildNumber>
  </snapshot>
  <lastUpdated>20210303091134</lastUpdated>
  <snapshotVersions>
    <snapshotVersion>
      <classifier>linux-amd64</classifier>
      <extension>tar.gz</extension>
      <value>1.1.0-20210303.085348-16</value>
      <updated>20210303085348</updated>
    </snapshotVersion>
    <snapshotVersion>
      <classifier>win-amd64</classifier>
      <extension>zip</extension>
      <value>1.1.0-20210303.090821-17</value>
      <updated>20210303090821</updated>
    </snapshotVersion>
    <snapshotVersion>
      <classifier>mac-x86_64</classifier>
      <extension>tar.gz</extension>
      <value>1.1.0-20210303.091119-18</value>
      <updated>20210303091119</updated>
    </snapshotVersion>
    ...
```

The snapshot version refers to a timestamp and build number that only exists for the MacOS artifact. So I can fetch the artifact `<groupId>:<artifactId>:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:mac-x86_64` but I cannot fetch `<groupId>:<artifactId>:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:linux-amd64`.

The deployment repository is an Artifactory server.

I don't know if this is a problem with Artifactory, or the maven-deploy-plugin, or if I am just doing something stupid. Is there a better way to handle deployment of platform-specific artifacts from multiple builds?